# How to reparameterize a curve $\gamma$ with lenght ${||y-x||}_2$ to get $x+t(y-x)$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

With $x,y \in {\mathbb{R}}^n$, a curve $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}^n$ with $\gamma (a)=x$, $\gamma (b)=y$ and $\gamma '(t) \neq 0$ $\forall t \in [a,b]$ and the length of $\gamma$ is ${||y-x||}_2$. And let ${||\cdot ||}_2$ be the euclidean norm.
Assuming $\gamma$ is parameterized, how do I have to reparameterize $\gamma$ such that $\gamma \circ \varphi(t)=x+t(y-x)$?

Greetings

Comment: This involves inverting $\gamma$. Tell us what $\gamma$ is.

Comment: $\varphi(t) = s$ where $\gamma(s) = x+t(y-x)$.

Comment: We only know that $\int_{a}^{b} ||\gamma ' (t)|| dt = ||\gamma (b) - \gamma (a)||$.
Why does it involve inverting $\gamma$?

Comment: And we know that $||\gamma '(t)||=1$, because $\gamma$ is parameterized.